# How to access deleted rows of parent table in child trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, transactions

I have 3 table(Main, Detail, SubDetail) with cascade delete relation. 
also define AFTER Trigger on SubDetail for check some data.

SubDetail Trigger need to join Detail table for some data but in case of Delete Detail record, i can't access Detail record.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DELETED JOIN Detail on DELETED.DetailId = Detail.Id
```

How to access deleted record of Detail table in SubDetail Trigger???

UPDATE:

Why Table Hint does not work in my scenario? it must do all in one transaction

Comment: So if you delete from `Detail` table - it deletes from `SubDetail` then why not use `after delete` trigger on `Details` table that will get related data from `SubDetail` table?

Comment: you right but I not like do this because has many relation! 
By cascade delete I can ensure that not forgot write code for any relation!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can't join to Defail table because the record does not exist in Detail table because you try to join AFTER DELETE and you have cascade delete. You could do this by using trigger INSTEAD OF 
or remove cascade delete and delete related record in after trigger 
or change order of deleting tables

Comment: Why sql server does not delete all cascade record then delete self record???  Please note that i print text on subDetail trigger and it show first!!

Comment: I run some tests and this answer is right. Even if you will put deleted from `details` rows in some history table and will try to join them in `subdetails` after delete trigger - that will not get data you needed.

Comment: @Hamid it's about an order of execution, for example: when you type DELETE FROM MAIN WHERE ID=... then sql server delete all referenced table in this example Detail, after deleting Detail it will delete Main and after that it will execute after trigger on Detail and on Main

Comment: I know, but if I raise error in AFTER TRIGGER (subDetail),  all operation rollback, therefore i must access deleted item with table hint like: SELECT * FROM Detail WITH(READCOMMITTED)